# Пожалуйста, исправьте ошибки

Tags: грамотная-речь

Если ты не веришь в чудеса, это равен тому, что ты не веришь в того, кто ёё создаёт, а её Создатель и наш Создатель. Не сотворил ли чудо, наш Создатель, создав всех нас ! Не чудо ли, что от болезни есть исцеление, не чудо ли, что есть необъятное небо, не чудо ли, что есть день и ночь, не чудо ли, когда обиженая мать, на ребёнка, всё равно будет любить его. Не замечающие чудес, постепенно забывают Создателья, и Всевышный заставит их, забыть самих себя, и они покидают этот мир, даже не зная зачем они пришли сюда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Текст после редактирования**

Если ты не веришь в чудеса, это всё равно что ты не веришь в того, кто их создаёт, а их Создатель и наш Создатель.

Не сотворил ли он чудо, создав всех нас? Не чудо ли, что от болезни есть исцеление, что есть необъятное небо, что есть день и ночь! Не чудо ли, что обиженная на ребенка мать всё равно будет любить его.

Не замечающие чудес постепенно забывают Создателя, а Всевышний заставит их забыть самих себя.  И тогда они покидают этот мир, даже не зная, зачем  пришли сюда.

**Примечание**

Из текста убраны повторы. Они могут быть художественным приемом, но при избытке становятся стилистической погрешностью.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Вашу помощь.